# Dynamic Height of a Row in an HTML Table

Tags: html, razor

I have a table on my page. Depending upon a selection, I could have 4 or 5 rows in my table.
I want my top row height to be exact whether I have 4 or 5 rows. Currently it increases the size of my top row when I have 4 rows in my table. Any ideas how to make the top row with same height every time?

Here is my table:

```
<table style="vertical-align:top; border-width:1px; border-style:solid; width:565px; height:155px; color:Black; font-size:8pt; left:19%; top:0px; position:absolute; border-color:Blue;">    
    <tr style="height:30px;">                        
        <td align="left" style="width:190px; font-size:9pt; font-weight:bold; height:30px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@(Model.PlanSummary.Header)</td>
        <td style="background-color:Red; width:130px; color:White; text-align:center; height:30px;">@(Model.PlanSummary.PlanTypes_1)</td>
        <td align="center" style="background-color:Red; width:130px; color:White; height:30px; text-align:center; height:30px;">@(Model.PlanSummary.PlanTypes_2)</td>
        <td align="center" style="background-color:Red; width:130px; color:White; height:30px; height:30px;">@(Model.PlanSummary.PlanTypes_3)</td>
    </tr>
    @{
        if(planName == "Business User")
        {
            <tr style="font-size:7pt;">
                <td align="left" style="width:190px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@(Model.PlanSummary.PlanUsersHeader) </td>
                <td align="center" style="width:120px;"> @(Model.PlanSummary.PlanUsersDetail1) </td>
                <td align="center" style="width:120px;"> @(Model.PlanSummary.PlanUsersDetail2) </td>               
                <td align="center" style="width:120px;"> @(Model.PlanSummary.PlanUsersDetail3) </td>
            </tr>   
        }        
     }
    <tr style="font-size:7pt;">
        <td align="left" style="width:190px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@(Model.PlanSummary.PlanPriceHeader)</td>
        <td align="center"> @(Model.PlanSummary.PlanPriceDetail1) </td>
        @{
            if(planName == "Business User")
            {
                <td align="center" style="width:120px; font-size: 9pt;"> 
                    @Html.DropDownList("RPUserPricingList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.PlanSummary.UserPricingList, new { style = "font-family: Verdana; font-size: 6pt; text-align:center; width:100px;" })                    
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="width:120px; font-size: 9pt;"> 
                    @Html.DropDownList("RPCompanyPricingList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.PlanSummary.ComanyPricingList, new { style = "font-family: Verdana; font-size: 6pt; text-align:center; width:90px;" })                    
                </td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td align="center"> @(Model.PlanSummary.PlanPriceDetail2) </td>      
                <td align="center"> @(Model.PlanSummary.PlanPriceDetail3) </td>
            }
         }                
    </tr>   
    <tr style="font-size:7pt;">
        <td align="left" style="width:190px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@(Model.PlanSummary.PlanUnitCountHeader)</td>
        <td align="center"> @(Model.PlanSummary.PlanUnitCountDetail1) </td>
        <td align="center"> @(Model.PlanSummary.PlanUnitCountDetail2) </td>
        <td align="center"> @(Model.PlanSummary.PlanUnitCountDetail3) </td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        @{
            if(planName == "Personal")
            {
                  <td align="center"><button style="background-image:url('Content/Images/ShortRedButton.png');color:White;width:86px;height:24px;font-size:6pt;">@(Model.PlanSummary.Btn1)</button></td>
                  <td align="center"><button style="background-image:url('Content/Images/ShortRedButton.png');color:White;width:86px;height:24px;font-size:6pt;">@(Model.PlanSummary.Btn2)</button></td>
                  <td align="center"><button style="background-image:url('Content/Images/ShortRedButton.png');color:White;width:86px;height:24px;font-size:6pt;">@(Model.PlanSummary.Btn3)</button></td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td align="center"><button style="background-image:url('Content/Images/ShortRedButton.png');color:White;width:86px;height:24px;font-size:6pt;">@(Model.PlanSummary.Btn1)</button></td>
                <td align="center"><button style="background-image:url('Content/Images/ShortRedButton.png');color:White;width:86px;height:24px;font-size:6pt;">@(Model.PlanSummary.Btn2)</button></td>
                <td align="center">
                    <button style="background-image:url('Content/Images/LongRedButton.png');color:White;width:96px;height:26px;font-size:6pt;">@(Model.PlanSummary.Btn3)</button>                            
                    <br />
                    <button style="background-image:url('Content/Images/LongRedButton.png');color:White;width:96px;height:26px;font-size:6pt;">@(Model.PlanSummary.Btn4)</button> 
                </td>
            }               
         }        
    </tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: I removed the height element from the table def. and it worked.

Comment: Add that as an answer and accept it. It's not only OK to answer your own questions, it's encouraged. An answer is easier to see than a comment. Plus, that will mark it as resolved so it won't show up in "unanswered" lists.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the height element from the table and it worked for me.
Thanks!!!!